# How to inject Google App Engine datastore with Guice?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dependency-injection, google-cloud-datastore, guice

I'm trying to inject Google App Engine's datastore via Guice into my service:

```
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    private final DatastoreService datastoreService;

    @Inject
    public FooServiceImpl (DatastoreService datastoreService) {
        this.datastoreService = datastoreService;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> No implementation for com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService was bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`@Provides`](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) method to your module:

```
@Provides
DatastoreService provideDatastoreService(){
    return DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
}
```